# Shopify: How would I see if a product in my cart had a specific tag

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to check if a item in my check out cart is a part of a collection(or if it has a specific tag).

Here is my "attempt" at trying to check if there is a product

```
{% for item in cart.items %}    
{% if item.product.collections == "SampleProduct" %}
  <p>Enjoy your Product</p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to check if your product is in a specific collection, you'll need something like this:

```
{% for item in cart.items %}  
  {% assign found_collection = false %}
  {% for collection in item.product.collections %}
    {% if found_collection == false and collection.title == 'SampleProduct' %}
      {% assign found_collection = true %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% if found_collection %}
    <p>Enjoy your Product</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or if you want to check for a tag, use this:

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
  {% if item.product.tags contains 'SampleProduct' %}
    <p>Enjoy your Product</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

For more info, see the Shopify wiki page for the [contains operator](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/contains).